# How to implement Duda White Label API into an HTML site?

Tags: php, html, css, api

I am trying to implement the Duda White Label API into a .html page so that it utilizes my custom CSS.

I am following the instructions here: https://support.dudamobile.com/API/API-Use-Cases/Multiscreen-White-Label-Setup

I have inserted my API and Password, as well as my custom url into the example php code and uploaded it as "dynamic.php" to my web server.

On my page I have the following as the body code:

```
    <section class="common_section">
    <div class="container">
    <?php require 'dynamic.php';?>
    </div>
    </section>
```

I have also tried include instead of require.  Both display nothing. I am mainly a front end designer so this is quite challenging. I feel like I am missing something huge. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I just went with an iframe and that worked. 
I'll leave this up for anyone else struggling with the Duda API.

```
    <section class="common_section">
    <div class="container">
    <iframe name="dynamic" src="dynamic.php" width="100%" height="6200px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    </section>
```